# Are There Any Hidden Costs to Passing Around a Struct With a Single Reference?

Tags: struct, d

I was recently reading [this](http://www.gamedev.net/blog/1140/entry-2250469-d-structs-vs-classes-and-a-simple-template-example/) article on structs and classes in D, and at one point the author comments that

> ...this is a perfect candidate for a struct. The reason is that it contains only one member, a pointer to an ALLEGRO_CONFIG. This means I can pass it around by value without care, as it's only the size of a pointer.

This got me thinking; is that really the case? I can think of a few situations in which believing you're passing a struct around "for free" could have some hidden gotchas.

Consider the following code:

```
struct S
{
    int* pointer;
}

void doStuff(S ptrStruct)
{
    // Some code here
}

int n = 123;
auto s = S(&n);
doStuff(s);
```

When s is passed to doStuff(), is a single pointer (wrapped in a struct) *really* all that's being passed to the function? Off the top of my head, it seems that any pointers to member functions would also be passed, as well as the struct's type information.

This wouldn't be an issue with classes, of course, since they're always reference types, but a struct's pass by value semantics suggests to me that any extra "hidden" data such as described above would be passed to the function along with the struct's pointer to int. This could lead to a programmer thinking that they're passing around an (assuming a 64-bit machine) 8-byte pointer, when they're actually passing around an 8-byte pointer, plus several other 8-byte pointers to functions, plus however many bytes an object's typeinfo is. The unwary programmer is then allocating far more data on the stack than was intended.

Am I chasing shadows here, or is this a valid concern when passing a struct with a single reference, and thinking that you're getting a struct that is a pseudo reference type? Is there some mechanism in D that prevents this from being the case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this question can be generalized to wrapping native types. E.g. you could make a SafeInt type which wraps and acts like an int, but throws on any integer overflow conditions.

There are two issues here:

1. Compilers may not optimize your code as well as with a native type.

   For example, if you're wrapping an int, you'll likely implement overloaded arithmetic operators. A sufficiently-smart compiler will inline those methods, and the resulting code will be no different than that as with an int. In your example, a dumb compiler might be compiling a dereference in some clumsy way (e.g. get the address of the struct's start, add the offset of the pointer field (which is 0), then dereference that).

   Additionally, when calling a function, the compiler may decide to pass the struct in some other way (due to e.g. poor optimization, or an ABI restriction). This could happen e.g. if the compiler doesn't pay attention to the struct's size, and treats all structs in the same way.
2. `struct` types in D may indeed have a hidden member, if you declare it in a function.

   For example, the following code works:

   ```
   import std.stdio;

   void main()
   {
       string str = "I am on the stack of main()";

       struct S
       {
           string toString() const { return str; }
       }

       S s;
       writeln(s);
   }
   ```

   It works because S saves a hidden pointer to main()'s stack frame. You can force a struct to not have any hidden pointers by prefixing `static` to the declaration (e.g. `static struct S`).

Comment: I didn't even consider compiler optimization and nested structs; those are some good points. Could you also address the concern I raised in my question about a struct's typeinfo and pointers to member functions?

Comment: As Zor has already said, that information is static (the information is in the compiler's memory), and is not part of each struct's instance. Adding any number of methods will not increase a struct's instance. Structs in D do not have RTTI, so the typeinfo is not a hidden member either.

Comment: Good point about nested structs, I forgot to address that. I'll add that it's highly unlikely that any current compiler treats a struct wrapping an int (for instance) any different than an int. I'm not so sure about the "paying attention to struct size" thing... not doing so would effectively violate the system ABI because the ABI mandates passing different-sized structs in different ways (e.g. in the System V x86-64 ABI, a struct of size < 16 is passed in registers, while larger structs are passed on the stack).

Comment: Sure, but I think we can't speak for all ABIs out there.

Answer (score 5):

There is no hidden data being passed. A `struct` consists exactly of what's declared in it (and any padding bytes if necessary), nothing else. There is no need to pass type information and member function information along because it's all *static*. Since a `struct` cannot inherit from another `struct`, there is no polymorphism.

Comment: Can you explain exactly what you mean by static? When you say static, I think of a static struct in the most literal sense, as in existent in memory for the duration of the program. Why does the fact that structs are "static" mean that no typeinfo and member function pointers need to be passed?

Comment: "Static" in the sense that a struct variable's (runtime) type and member accesses can all be completely determined at compile time. `Since a struct cannot inherit from another struct, there is no polymorphism` - so structs have no virtual functions and therefore no need to include a table of method pointers with each instance. Similarly, the lack of struct subclassing means that the compile-time type of a struct variable is always the same as its runtime type, so no typeinfo needed.